# Refresh component in sencha touch 2

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch-2

I'm facing a problem in sencha touch 2 that a given component isnt being updated after I set the HTML. I mean sometimes it gets updated and sometimes not, in the exact same test cases.

I was looking for a way to force the component to repaint itself but I can't seem to find the way.

Also the component gets refreshed perfectly fine on android but not on iOS.

So the question is, is there a method to make a panel repaint in sencha touch 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you described, it seems that there's no error in your implementation. This is sometimes a bug.

To force everything to be re-rendered, this trick may help:

```
yourComponent.hide();
yourComponent.show();
```

Actually it forces Sencha Touch to re-calculate your component layout and sub-components, as well as contents. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of my head it seems like a problem with the component IDs, make sure you don't have duplicated IDs. It's a pretty common mistake in ExtJS and Sencha Touch and produces the described behavior